# Geocoding a list of addresses from a CSV file

Tags: python, csv, geocoding

I am trying to geocode a list of addresses in a CSV file. The column with the information is named "full" and it looks like this:

```
full
100 Ross St,15219
1014 Blackadore Ave.,15208
1026 Winterton St.,15206
...
```

This is the code that I am using:

```
import csv
import pygeocoder
import pandas as pd

from pygeocoder import Geocoder

df = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\Jesus\Desktop\Events.csv')
address = df.full

result = Geocoder.geocode(address)
print(result[0].coordinates)
```

And this is the output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jesus\Desktop\python\geocode.py", line 10, in <module>
    result = Geocoder.geocode(address)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pygeocoder.py", line 160, in geocode
    return GeocoderResult(Geocoder.get_data(params=params))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pygeocoder.py", line 107, in get_data
    response_json = response.json()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 693, in json
    return json.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\simplejson\__init__.py", line 488, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\simplejson\decoder.py", line 370, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\simplejson\decoder.py", line 389, in raw_decode
    return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\simplejson\scanner.py", line 122, in scan_once
    return _scan_once(string, idx)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\simplejson\scanner.py", line 118, in _scan_once
    raise JSONDecodeError(errmsg, string, idx)
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0
```

Comment: Couldn't you just upload the list to a geocoding service and then get the results back?

Comment: I could but would I learn something new?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `address` variable is a Series object from pandas, which may be causing this problem. To geocode all the addresses from the CSV, iterate through it like:

```
for a in address:
    result = Geocoder.geocode(a)
    print(result[0].coordinates)
```

To store the results in a file (assuming Python 2.x):

```
with open('filename', 'w') as outfile:
    for a in address:
        result = Geocoder.geocode(a)
        print >>outfile, str(result[0].coordinates) # Prints to file
```

You can do `outfile.write( str(result[0].coordinates) )` instead of the print if you want. The only difference is that `print` automatically adds a line break. To add to a list, just declare the list outside of your `for` statement (such as `coordinates_list = []`) and replace the `print` with `coordinates_list.append(result[0].coordinates)`. Either of these ways will work in Python 3.x, but the `print >>outfile` statement will not.

Comment: And what if I wanted to save the print results to a file or a list?

Comment: Edited the answer with instructions.